# AG-Grid tree data structure

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am moving from kendo tree list to ag grid tree data grid. I have my table data in   below format. But Ag grid expect data in string array of nodes in tree. How can I use/customize below data with ag grid.

```
[  
   {  
      "fieldId":"A",
      "parentId":null,     
   },
   {  
      "fieldId":"B",
      "parentId":A,     
   },
   {  
      "fieldId":"C",
      "parentId":B,     
   },
]
```

I was able to create ag grid for only 1 level hierarchy using "getDataPath" like below but not able to understand how i can do for higher level hierarchy

```
this.getDataPath = function (data) {
    return [data.parentId, data.fieldId];
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop-scan for it:

```js
let data = [
  {"fieldId":"A", "parentId":null}, 
  {"fieldId":"B", "parentId":"A"},
  {"fieldId":"C", "parentId":"A"},
  {"fieldId":"D", "parentId":"B"},
  {"fieldId":"E", "parentId":"D"}
];
function getParentLoop(fieldId, path){
  let p = data.filter(i=>i.fieldId == fieldId)[0];
  if(p.parentId){
    path.unshift(p.fieldId);
    return getParentLoop(p.parentId, path)
  } 
  else {
    path.unshift(p.fieldId);
  }
  return path;
}
data.map(i=>{
  i.path=[]
  if(i.parentId){
    i.path.push(i.fieldId);
    getParentLoop(i.parentId, i.path);
  }
  else{
    i.path.push(i.fieldId)
  }
  return i;
});
console.log(data);
```

```
this.getDataPath = function (data) {
    return data.path;
};
```

Comment: Basically great solution. But why not push i.fieldId into i.path before calling getParentLoop?

Comment: @mila seems just a typo, cuz it doesn't affect on the result